# Problem resource not found

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Every one,  
I'm a newbie on ROS and Gazebo and for my student project, I'm using ROS Melodic and I'm trying to use this tutorial : [ainstein_radar_gazebo](http://wiki.ros.org/ainstein_radar_gazebo_plugins) I can compile with no error but when I want to launch, I have one :

```
Resource not found: The following package was not found in <arg name="world_name" value="$(find gazebo_radar_sensor_plugin)/worlds/test.world"/>: gazebo_radar_sensor_plugin ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/melodic/share/ros ROS path [1]=/home/thomaspc/catkin_ws/src ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/melodic/share The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

In the tutorial, they say I have to fill the bashrc with this :

```
export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH:~/.gazebo/models
```

and this :

```
export GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=$GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH:~/catkin_ws/devel/lib
```

I don't understand my mistake and even after some research

Could you hepl me please 
thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353161/problem-resource-not-found/) by [KoalaDangerous](https://answers.ros.org/users/55073/koaladangerous/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-05-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @KoalaDangerous,

The following command: `export GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=$GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH:~/catkin_ws/devel/lib` is to inform Gazebo about the location of custom Gazebo plugins.

This one: `export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH:~/.gazebo/models` explicitly tells Gazebo where to find its model to spawn in the world.

You have to take into account multiple things:

1. You will have to [source](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment) properly your workspace.
2. These are envirtomental variables that are only set within the scope of one terminal. Meaning that the will be set and used on those bash enviroments you performed the `export` command.
3. The second command redirects to a hidden folder where Gazebo stores its model. Either you copy/move the model folder of the `ainstein_radar_gazebo` to this folder or you export the variable with the project folder containing the radar model.

E.g.: `export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH:~.../ainstein_radar_gazebo_plugins/models`

---

Originally posted by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) with karma: 1695 on 2020-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0